# WordPressのプラグインJetPackのPhoton機能を使ってキャッシュされた画像の削除方法

Tags: wordpress

WordPressのプラグインJetPack内の
Photonを使ってブログ内の画像をキャッシュさせていた所
間違った画像が含まれていた為メディア・記事内から削除したのですが
キャッシュされた画像が消せません

消し方を教えてください

Comment: 記事内のリンク記述の削除および
メディアから削除してサーバー内にデータが残っていないことは確認しました。
Nginxのキャッシュの全削除も試みました。が消えておりません。

Answer (score 1):

JetPack プラグインの Photon にはキャッシュの削除機能がありません。
その為、間違った画像のファイル名を変えるなどして対応する必要があると思います。

[Photon — Jetpack for WordPress](http://jetpack.me/support/photon/)

> If you want to “refresh” an image you will need to change the name of the image.

また、原文ではキャッシュバスターを付加しても意味がないことも書かれています。
キャッシュバスターとは、`hoge.jpg?v={アクセスするたびにランダムな文字列}` のようにクエリパラメータを付加し、常に新しいリソースを取得しようとすることです。

> Adding random query arguments, commonly known as cachebusters, will not work.